# Comparing Data Graphs Using C# GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, hash, oauth, gethashcode

I have a graph of data that I'm pulling from an OAuth source using several REST calls and storing relationally in a database.  The data structure ends up having about 5-10 tables with several one-to-many relationships.  I'd like to periodically go a re-retrieve that information to see if updates are necessary in my database.

Since I'm going to be doing this for many users and their data will likely not change very often, my goal is to minimize the load on my database unnecessarily. My strategy is to query the data from my OAuth provider but then hash the results and compare it to the last hash that I generated for the same dataset.  If the hashes don't match, then I would simply start a transaction in the database, blow away all the data for that user, re-write the data, and close the transaction.  This saves me the time of reading in the data from the database and doing all the compare work to see what's changed, what rows were added, deleted changed etc.

So my question:  if I glue all my data together in memory as a big string and use C# GetHasCode(), is that fairly reliable mechanism to check if my data has changed?  Or, are there any better techniques to skinning this cat?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a fairly reliable mechanism to detect changes. I do not know about the probabilty of collisions in the GetHashCode() Method, but I'd assume it to be safe.

Better methods: Can't the data have a version-stamp or timestamp that is set everytime something changes?

Comment: Agreed, a timestamp approach would be best but unfortunately I don't think my provider has timestamp "coverage" across the entire data graph.  There are some timestamps but they only apply to certain fields.  I might get some mileage there by comparing those timestamps up front but I think 99% of the time I'm going to need to fall back to a raw comparison of some sort.  I guess I'll start checking the collision characteristics of the string.GetHasCode() method...